# How to get rid of table row heading duplication?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to show a simple hard-coded data in a table view using vue.js. So far everything works, but I get a new heading for every row of data being presented (Title, Year, Details), instead of having only one row for titles.

The vue.js file:

```
class Post {
constructor(title, year, details) {
    this.title = title;
    this.year = year;
    this.details = details;
}
}

const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    search: '',
    postList: [
        new Post(
            'Movie1',
            '1987',
            'Details here'
        ),
        new Post(
            'Movie2',
            '2006'
        ),
        new Post(
            'Movie3',
            '1999',
        ),
    ]
    },
    computed: {
    filteredList() {
        return this.postList.filter(post => {
            return 
  post.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
        })
    }
}
})
```

And the Index:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js">
```

```
<div id="app">
<div class="search-wrapper">
    <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search" />
</div>
<br />
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="card" v-for="post in filteredList">
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Release date</th>
                <th>Details</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ post.title }}</td>
                <td>{{ post.year }}</td>
                <td>{{ post.details }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm thinking it has something to do on the HTML-side, I'm suspecting its the use of v-for directive for rendering?

Comment: Why the `C#` and `asp.net` tags?

Comment: Use the `v-for` in the `<tr>` containing the data maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v-for is directive that will loop on each element of your array and render all the child element for each elements of you array.
You should put your v-for like that :

```
<table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Release date</th>
                    <th>Details</th>
                </tr>
                <tr v-for="post in filteredList">
                    <td>{{ post.title }}</td>
                    <td>{{ post.year }}</td>
                    <td>{{ post.details }}</td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

See [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) for more about v-for directive